# Django image has no file associated even though I have blank and null

Tags: python, html, css, django

When a user signs up I used to have it so that an image got applied to that users account. But due to file locations I cannot have it like that anymore, so I am trying to have it so when a user signs up, it leaves the image field blank, so I can render a fake default image on the template. But when a user signs up, or view's there profile or logs in it throws an `The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.` error. I thought I could get around this by having `blank=True` and `null=True`, but for some reason it keeps throwing this error.

Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Profile Picture', upload_to='profile_pictures', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Views:

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    review = Post.objects.filter(live=False, author=request.user)
    post = Post.objects.filter(live=True, author=request.user)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'post': post,
        'review': review
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

HTML:

```
{% if user.profile.image.url %}
                <div class="profile-image">
                    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="{{ user.profile.image }}">
                </div>
                {% elif user.profile.image.url == None %}
                <div class="profile-image">
                    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{% static '/public/images/default.jpg' %}" alt="{{ user.profile.image }}">
                </div>
                {% endif %}
```

Would be great if anyone has any type of solution.

Comment: If a field has `blank=True` and `null=True`, that means that field is not required. So in this case, it means profiles can be created without images.  You'll have to manually check if the profile has an image before trying to open it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should **add a check** in Profile's `save` method.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    super().save()

    if self.image:
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Also, you have to check the `image` object in the template and then access to `url` attribute and do a preview. Here is how.

```
{% if user.profile.image %}
    <div class="profile-image">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="{{ user.profile.image }}">
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="profile-image">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{% static '/public/images/default.jpg' %}" alt="{{ user.profile.image }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```